# How to assign a value to a Range created with Cells() in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I want to assign a value to multiple cells using a `Range`. I must define the range using variables, that's why I use the `Cells()` parameters, but when I create a Range object with `Cells`, the compilator returns a 1004 error (Application-defined or object-defined error).
The error also occurs when not using variables, for example with `Range(Cells(0,0), Cells(1,0))`.

Here is my code

```
Dim Offset1 As Integer: Offset1 = 0
Dim Offset2 As Integer: Offset2 = 1
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  .Range(.Cells(Offset1, 0), .Cells(Offset2, 0)).Value = "NewValue"
End With
```

Comment: You need to offset something, you can't use .Cells() with a 0 column if you're not offsetting another cell.  It needs to be 1 or above for a normal .Cells() call.  There is no 0 column.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells` would be the entire worksheet - you can't offset that in any direction.  Similarly `Range("B2").Cells(0, 0).Address` is A1 (because `Cells()` uses one-based indexing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few questions around your attempt but let me spell it out for you.

If you want to use the `.Range()` approach then it requires a qualified range of cells as the parameter.

This is what is expected (obviously within a `With` statement) ...

```
.Range("A1:B10").Value = "NewValue"
```

... and if you want something like that but want it to be somewhat dynamic, then this as specified will produce the same result.  You need to use `.Address` along with a proper row/column cell reference.

```
.Range(.Cells(1, 1).Address & ":" & .Cells(10, 2).Address).Value = "NewValue"
```

`.Cells(1, 1)` = Cell A1

`.Cells(10, 2)` = Cell B10

If you want to offset a specific cell, then you need a proper cell reference to begin with.  Example, if you want 2 columns to the right and 5 rows down from cell B10, you would do this ...

```
.Cells(10, 2).Offset(5, 2).Address
```

You should be able to adapt that to your code.